# WebRTC for Universal Windows Platform

Tags: android, webrtc, win-universal-app, p2p

We'd like to implement a prototype that allows Android native app to send file to Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10) using WebRTC.

I know WebRTC has native sdk for android
https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

But I can't seem to find how Universal Windows Platform app can support WebRTC.

Please kindly help.

thanks